# Spring Data JPA: overriding toPredicate when inner object's variable is criteria

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I want to create method which will find all the A class objects, which specificValues contains SpecificValue class object with name == value.

```
@Entity
Class A {
 String variable;

 @ManyToMany
 List<SpecificValue> specificValues = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
Class SpecificValue {
 String name;

 @ManyToMany
 List<A> As = new Arraylist<>();
}
```

If I want to find all by variable I can just make it this way:

```
public static Specification<A> variable(String variable) {
 return(r, cq, cb) -> cb.like(r.get("variable", "%" + variable + "%");
}
```

But I have problems with writing proper predicate when I have to look through list of other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

just added new method in my Repository

```
List<A> findBySpecificValues_name(String name);
```